# Javascript regular expression max decimal(7,2)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, regex

I have a decimal which is set up as decimal(7,2) in the DB. I have a JS regular expression validator and can't figure out how to validate the input in a textbox to this DB decimal setup.

```
function ValidateBoxes(input) {
    var valid = (input.match(/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/));

    if (valid = null) {
        alert("Decimals have a max value of 99999.99")
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `input.match(/^\d{0,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/)`. (mantissa digit count corrected; anyway you have to decide whether no digits before or following the decimal point should be allowed)

Comment: In case, If you want to trim you can use `input.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` is intended to return the grouped matches for further processing, but if you just want to test whether or not the input matches the regex, try `regex.test` rather than `string.match`, like so:

```
/^\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(input); // true or false
```

Comment: That's because `99999.` doesn't match the regex.  If you want it to match, change the second grouping to `0, 2` to allow "nothing" (specifically 0-2 digits) after the period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
input.match(/^\d{1,5}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/)
```